# How to get value in textbox from barcode reader using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I want to take value from barcode reader to textbox. I have tvs 101 platina (barcode reader)
i am new in vb.net plz provide me solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just giving a start :

1st here is a programme manual: http://www.tvs-e.in/pos/pdf/Programming_Guide_BS-L101-Platina.pdf

2nd the article that i used before : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/296533/Using-a-bar-code-scanner-in-NET

What you have to do:

Scanner is similer to keyboard. so you need key event listener for focusing on text field.

programme the scanner to send the special key code for start and end of scan.(it will be given in the manual)

Comment: I read all the above but i m not able to programme the scanner to send the special key code for start and end of scan...

Comment: sorry! i don't have that scanner so can't help anymore.

Comment: if you have basic programming idea of any bar reader then show the source code.

Comment: thanks I have done it... there was problem in my bar reader device...